# Trying to remove each digit from my output, like a right triangle

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, numbers, printf

I'm trying to make my program remove every last digit going down to each row.

Where I'm stuck on and don't understand why `number = number % 10` won't work within the second for loop?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
    
int main(){
    long long number;
    
    printf("Enter a number\n");
    printf("Enter your number = ");
    scanf("%d", &number);
    
    for(int j=1; j<= (log10(number)+1); j++){
        for(int i=1; i<= (log10(number)+1); i++){
            printf("%d   ", (number%((int)pow(10, i)))/(int)pow(10, i-1));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

My output:

```
Enter a number
Enter your number = 12345
5   4   3   2   1
5   4   3   2   1
5   4   3   2   1
5   4   3   2   1
5   4   3   2   1
```

What I'm trying to output:

```
Enter a number
Enter your number = 12345
5   4   3   2   1
5   4   3   2
5   4   3
5   4
5
```

Comment: You invoked *undefined behavior* by using `%d` and passing `long long*` instead of expected `int*` to `scanf()`. Also `number = number % 10` is not in your posted code. Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: `number = number % 10` breaks `number`, so it is harmful in the inner loop unless the data in `number` is saved in some other place.

Comment: But is the %d a problem?? it didn't seem like it was affecting it. Should I make a new variable?

Comment: `%d` *is* a problem. [I got wrong result](https://ideone.com/8eDBlf). It don't have direct relationship to `number = number % 10` though.

Comment: `%lld` should be used to read `long long`. The removing can be done by changing `i<= (log10(number)+1)` to `i<= (log10(number)+1) - (j - 1)`.

Comment: Would, this word?? scanf("%d", &number && &number2)
printf("%d   ", (number2%((int)pow(10, i)))/(int)pow(10, i-1));

Comment: `scanf("%d", &number && &number2)` is wrong. The type of `&number && &number2` is `int` and its value will be `1` (because typically pointers of variables won't be zero). Passing `1` to where valid pointer is required will lead to Segmentation Fault.

Comment: I'm sorry I might be a bit lost, I'm new to programming and C language.

Comment: I fixed the (long long number) in the scanf() to %11d, thanks for that tip. I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong or maybe I'm overthinking it and don't need a double for loop?

Comment: You won't need double `for` loop, but using double `for` loop should be easier. By the way, you used `%11d` (one one d) instead of `%lld`? `%11d` is `%d` with length specified and it will also invoke *undefined behavior* when used with `long long*`.

Comment: Oh ya I did use "%11d" thank you for your catch I just changed it to  "%lld"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing `number = number % 10` in the second `for` loop is a bad idea because it breaks the data in `number`.

To remove digits, you should reduce the number to print in the inner loop.

This means

```
    for(int j=1; j<= (log10(number)+1); j++){
        for(int i=1; i<= (log10(number)+1); i++){
```

should be

```
    for(int j=1; j<= (log10(number)+1); j++){
        for(int i=1; i<= (log10(number)+1) - (j-1); i++){
```

so that the iteration in the inner loop is reduced according to `j`.

Also note that

```
long long number;
scanf("%d", &number);
```

invokes *undefined behavior* because `%d` in `scanf()` requires `int*` but `long long*` is passed instead of that.

To read `long long` via `scanf()` you should use `%lld`.

```
long long number;
scanf("%lld", &number);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, that just helped me solve the problem I was stuck on.

Comment: I'm also guessing  printf("%d   ", (number%((int)pow(10, i)))/(int)pow(10, i-1)); needs to change the "%d" to "%11d" also?

Comment: Ah, it also should be `%lld` (not `%11d`)

Comment: Yup just changed it to "%lld"

Answer (score 0):

Appending other answers I would suggest as an alternative solution to use a recursive function (without calling any mathematical function) to output a given number.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

FILE * output( unsigned long long n, FILE *fp )
{
    const unsigned long long Base = 10;
    
    if ( n / Base != 0 )
    {
        output( n / Base, fp );
        fprintf( fp, "   " );
    }
    
    fprintf( fp, "%llu", n % Base );

    return fp;
}

int main(void) 
{
    const unsigned long long Base = 10;
    
    while ( 1 )
    {
        printf( "Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): " );
        
        unsigned long long n;
        
        if ( !( scanf( "%llu", &n ) == 1 ) || ( n == 0 ) ) break;
        
        putchar( '\n' );
        
        do
        {
            fputc( '\n', output( n, stdout ) );
        } while ( n /= Base );
        
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 987654321

9   8   7   6   5   4   3   2   1
9   8   7   6   5   4   3   2
9   8   7   6   5   4   3
9   8   7   6   5   4
9   8   7   6   5
9   8   7   6
9   8   7
9   8
9

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 0
```